# Cyclic Groups Other than $\mathbb{Z}^*_n$ or Elliptic Curves

Tags: group-theory

I see two types of cyclic groups are most commonly used in cryptography:

- modulo multiplicative group of integers with prime order
- elliptic curves

Are there any other cyclic groups used in cryptography?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The multiplicative group $\mathbb{F}_{2^n}^{\ast}$ (which is cyclic) is used in defining LFSR sequences and nonlinearly filtered sequences typically as building blocks of stream ciphers.

This group is part of the picture for block ciphers; most prominently, the field $\mathbb{F}_{2^n}$ is used (for $n=8$) for defining the AES. Boolean functions and vector boolean functions defined over $\mathbb{F}_{2^n}$ also appear.

Comment: Koblitz curves are also over the field $\mathbb{F}^{*}_{2^n}$.